# how to get the value of active list or clicked list of an unordered list in servlet

Tags: jquery, servlets

i want to get the value of the active list or clicked list of an unordered list from jsp in servlet. And I am using for each loop of jstl in my jsp page. For each list I am providing a submit button which is my requirement. I have to get the value of that particular list in servlet which is associated to that submit button. And here is my code. Thank you.

```
<ul>
  <c:forEach items="${subjectList.subtopicsList}" var="subtopicList">
    <li id='subtopicId' name='subtopicName'>
      <c:out value="${subtopicList.subTopicName}"/>
        <input type="submit" class="login-button" value='BeginTest'>
    </li>
  </c:forEach>
</ul>
```

Comment: You want get value when clicked submit button?

Comment: yes, exactly @Norlihazmey Ghazali.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it. We can get the value of clicked list in servlet as follows:

In jsp,

```
<c:forEach items="${subjectList.subtopicsList}" var="subtopicList">
                                                <li class='subtopicId' name='subtopicName' value='${subtopicList.subTopicId}'>
                                                    <c:out value="${subtopicList.subTopicName}" />
                                                    <input type="submit" class="login-button" value='BeginTest' onclick="form.action='<%=path%>/VerificationAction?subtopicId='+${subtopicList.subTopicId}">
                                                </li>
                                            </c:forEach>
```

And in servlet, get the value as follows:

int subtopicId=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("subtopicId"));

Answer (score 0):

If so, change the id of li to the class definition, because the ids should be unique. Use class instead, Like below:

```
 <ul>
   <c:forEach items="${subjectList.subtopicsList}" var="subtopicList">
     <li class='subtopicId' name='subtopicName'>
       <c:out value="${subtopicList.subTopicName}"/>
       <input type="submit" class="login-button" value='BeginTest'>
     </li>
  </c:forEach>
  </ul>
```

Js

```
 <script>
$(function(){
   $(document).on('click','.login-button', function(){
     var listData = $(this).closest('li.subtopicId').text();
      alert(listData);
   });
 });
 </script>
```

P/s: i dont have any ideas how jsp works, but that is how to get the value of particular submit and it li text by using jquery. Hope this help.

Comment: actually I want that li value in servlet. Also i have added value in li tag as below:   <li class='subtopicId' name='subtopicName' value='${subtopicList.subTopicId}'>

Comment: If you put the value as attribute in li tag, then change this code   `$(this).closest('li.subtopicId').text()` into           `$(this).closest('li.subtopicId').attr('value');`, Instead of using value as attribute, you can use data attribute for user defined attribute

Comment: @ Norlihazmey Ghazali , I want that li value in my servlet

Comment: I think i'm not completly understand what you want. Lol. I thought you wanna get the li value when button was clicked. Should remove this answer. Sorry dude.